# Can't return any values from ttyUSB0

Tags: raspbian, usb, linux, serial, ubuntu

I'm using a SICK S300 scanner connected via Diagnostic cable to my Raspberry Pi, and it shows the connection as /dev/ttyUSB0 however I can't retrieve any data from it whatsoever.

Here is a simple Python program I am using to attempt to read the incoming data.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)
```

I'm expecting to some degree a string of hex characters to be read from the device.

Here is the [SICK Cable](https://www.bpx.co.uk/store/product/6034574).

There must be some level of data coming out as the Windows software that comes with it is capable of reading the data and displaying it for testing/diagnostic purposes.

I am able to retreive data using an RS422 cable.

Comment: Are you using the following user manual? https://cdn.sick.com/media/docs/3/13/613/Operating_instructions_S300_Safety_laser_scanner_en_IM0017613.PDF. I don't find any spec of UART interface of the S300 Diagonstic Cable.  Do you have a S300 to UART adaptor?

Comment: I guess you might have a RS422 to UART adapter. Then your S300 can connect and talk to Rpi. You need to first make sure the S300 side is outputting something, using a scope/analyzier perhaps, or seeing the status LEDs blinking.  You also need to know the protocol such as baud rate 9,600 baud 8N1 etc, and the very basic hello/bye (AT/OK) command list to get started. https://answers.ros.org/question/331161/how-to-connect-sick-s300-expert-to-pc-for-ros/

Comment: I've updated the question with some more information to try and answer your questions. I'm going to pursue an RS422 connection rather than the USB diagnostic connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an RS422 to USB connection I was able to recieve data through the same port /dev/ttyUSB0